# How to I stop menu from automatically dropping down showing items when I hover?

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, hover, mainmenu

When I am clicking on a item on my menu specifically on mobile, the first item sub items keeps dropping down and it interferres with my selection. Please help it is very annoying

I want the menu to only dropdown when I click the item. I have tried a few css from threads but nothing seems to be working

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There is absolutely no way we can help you with the information provided. There are 1000s of WP themes that handle everything differently.

Comment: what information woild you need to assist me?Please help.